# Performing one-off calculations within a SQL query

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, unix-timestamp, epoch, compile-time-constant

I have this query (edited for simplicity):

```
select to_timestamp(s.sampletimestamp/1000)
from sample s
where s.sampletimestamp >= extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-11 00:00:00+10')*1000 and
s.sampletimestamp < extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-12 00:00:00+10')*1000
order by s.sampletimestamp;
```

I notice that this executes much quicker by entering values for the time manually:

```
select to_timestamp(s.sampletimestamp/1000)
from sample s
where s.sampletimestamp >= 1376143200000 and
s.sampletimestamp < 1376229600000
order by s.sampletimestamp;
```

Where the time is an epoch time stamp in milliseconds. My guess is that the computer is evaluating the `extract(EPOCH...)` part for every record, whereas it only really needs to do that once.

Is there someway to keep the more human-readable form of the first query, whilst keeping the query as efficient as the second?

I am new to PostgreSQL (and entirely self-taught), so I think the problem I'm mostly suffering from is not knowing a particular keyword I should be putting into google - which I've already used as well as the PostgreSQL documentation.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT1: Thanks for the very detailed replies. I suspect I'm probably in a different time zone to most of the respondants - I'll provide experimental evidence for this tomorrow (it's very late here).

EDIT2: To summarise the answer below, casting with 'bigint' does the trick. Replace:

```
where s.sampletimestamp >= extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-11 00:00:00+10')*1000 and
s.sampletimestamp < extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-12 00:00:00+10')*1000
```

With:

```
where s.sampletimestamp >= extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-11 00:00:00+10')::bigint*1000 and
s.sampletimestamp < extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-12 00:00:00+10')::bigint*1000
```

Comment: what version of PostgreSQL do you using?

Comment: Since there's no reference to any columns in that expression I'm pretty sure it should be pre-computed just once. Very strange. Can you supply the output of `select version()` and a self-contained test case that demonstrates this without relying on data we don't have available to us here? (edit) aha, never mind, I know what's going on.

Comment: could you try `select to_timestamp(s.sampletimestamp/1000)
from sample s
where s.sampletimestamp >= extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-11 00:00:00+10')::bigint*1000 and
s.sampletimestamp < extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-12 00:00:00+10')::bigint*1000
order by s.sampletimestamp;`. It could be because of types conversion

Comment: BTW: is there any real reason to use a bigint "timestamp" datatype, instead of a "timestamp",  which would allow all the operations , including date_trunc() ? (even at sub-second level)

Comment: Yep, the 'bigint' cast does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is that `extract` is implemented using the `date_part` function:

```
regress=> explain select count(1) from generate_series(1376143200000,1376143200000+1000000) x where x > extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-11 00:00:00+10')*1000 and x <  extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-12 00:00:00+10')*1000;
                                                                                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=30.02..30.03 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Function Scan on generate_series x  (cost=0.00..30.00 rows=5 width=0)
         Filter: (((x)::double precision > (date_part('epoch'::text, '2013-08-10 22:00:00+08'::timestamp with time zone) * 1000::double precision)) AND ((x)::double precision < (date_part('epoch'::text, '2013-08-11 22:00:00+08'::timestamp with time zone) * 1000::double precision)))
(3 rows)
```

`date_part(text, timestamptz)` is defined as `stable` not `immutable`:

```
regress=> \df+ date_part
                                                                                                                 List of functions
   Schema   |   Name    | Result data type |        Argument data types        |  Type  | Volatility |  Owner   | Language |                               Source code                                |                 Description                 
------------+-----------+------------------+-----------------------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------
 ...
 pg_catalog | date_part | double precision | text, timestamp with time zone    | normal | stable     | postgres | internal | timestamptz_part                                                         | extract field from timestamp with time zone
 ...
```

and I'm pretty sure that'll prevent Pg from pre-computing the value and inlining it into the call. I'd need to dig deeper to be sure.

I believe the reasoning is that `date_part` on a `timestamptz` can be dependent on the value of the `TimeZone` setting. This isn't true for `date_part('epoch', some_timestamptz)` but the query planner doesn't understand at planning time that you're using that.

I'm still surprised that it doesn't get pre-computed, as [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html) states:

> A `STABLE` function cannot modify the database and is guaranteed to return the same results given the same arguments for all rows within a single statement. This category allows the optimizer to optimize multiple calls of the function to a single call.

You can work around this apparent limitation by converting to a timestamp at UTC (or whatever the TZ the epoch of your times is in) first, with `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`. E.g.:

```
select count(1) 
from generate_series(1376143200000,1376143200000+1000000) x 
where x > extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-11 00:00:00+10' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')*1000 
and x <  extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-12 00:00:00+10' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')*1000;
```

This executes faster, though there's more time difference than I'd expect if it were just being calculated once:

```
regress=> select count(1) from generate_series(1376143200000,1376143200000+1000000) x where x > extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-11 00:00:00+10')*1000 and x <  extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-12 00:00:00+10')*1000;
  count  
---------
 1000000
(1 row)

Time: 767.629 ms

regress=> select count(1) from generate_series(1376143200000,1376143200000+1000000) x where x > extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-11 00:00:00+10' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')*1000 and x <  extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-12 00:00:00+10' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')*1000;
  count  
---------
 1000000
(1 row)

Time: 373.453 ms

regress=> select count(1) from generate_series(1376143200000,1376143200000+1000000) x where x > 1376143200000 and x <  1376229600000;
  count  
---------
 1000000
(1 row)

Time: 324.557 ms
```

It would be possible to remove this query optimizer limitation / add a feature to optimize this. The optimizer would need to recognize, probably at parse time, that `extract('epoch', ...)` is a special case and instead of invoking `date_part('epoch, ...)` invoke a special `timestamptz_epoch(...)` function that was immutable.

A bit of looking at `perf top` results shows that the timestamptz case has the following peaks:

```
 10.33%  postgres      [.] ExecMakeFunctionResultNoSets
  7.76%  postgres      [.] timesub.isra.1
  6.94%  postgres      [.] datebsearch
  5.58%  postgres      [.] timestamptz_part
  3.82%  postgres      [.] AllocSetAlloc
  2.97%  postgres      [.] ExecEvalConst
  2.68%  postgres      [.] downcase_truncate_identifier
  2.38%  postgres      [.] ExecEvalScalarVarFast
  2.23%  postgres      [.] slot_getattr
  1.99%  postgres      [.] DatumGetFloat8
```

wheras with the use of `AT TIME ZONE` we get:

```
 11.58%  postgres      [.] ExecMakeFunctionResultNoSets
  4.28%  postgres      [.] AllocSetAlloc
  4.18%  postgres      [.] ExecProject
  3.82%  postgres      [.] slot_getattr
  2.99%  libc-2.17.so  [.] __memmove_ssse3
  2.96%  postgres      [.] BufFileWrite
  2.80%  libc-2.17.so  [.] __memcpy_ssse3_back
  2.74%  postgres      [.] BufFileRead
  2.69%  postgres      [.] float8lt
```

and with the integer case:

```
  7.92%  postgres      [.] ExecMakeFunctionResultNoSets
  5.36%  postgres      [.] slot_getattr
  4.52%  postgres      [.] AllocSetAlloc
  4.02%  postgres      [.] ExecProject
  3.42%  libc-2.17.so  [.] __memmove_ssse3
  3.33%  postgres      [.] BufFileWrite
  3.31%  libc-2.17.so  [.] __memcpy_ssse3_back
  2.91%  postgres      [.] BufFileRead
  2.90%  postgres      [.] GetMemoryChunkSpace
  2.67%  postgres      [.] AllocSetFree
```

So you can see that the `AT TIME ZONE` version avoids the repeated `timestamptz_part` and `datebsearch` calls. The main difference between it and the integer case is `float8lt`; it looks like we're doing `double precision` comparisons instead of integer comparisons.

Sure enough, a cast takes care of it:

```
select count(1) 
from generate_series(1376143200000,1376143200000+1000000) x
where x > extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-11 00:00:00+10' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::bigint * 1000  
and x <  extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-08-12 00:00:00+10' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::bigint * 1000;
```

I don't have the time to pursue the enhancement to the optimizer discussed above at present, but it's something you might want to consider raising on the mailing list.

Comment: I think the problem is in the extract() function yielding a DOUBLE PRECISION value, and the generator is not allowed to type-coerce that "down" into an integer type, not even for a constant expression.

Comment: @RomanPekar Yep, though it's a smaller effect than the repeat execution of `date_part` on the timestamptz.